# Reveal in finder does not work with concatenated string

Tags: applescript

Why does this work:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    reveal POSIX file ("/Users/Torben/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/MyFolder/file.png")
end tell
```

...but not this

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    reveal POSIX file ("/Users/Torben/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/MyFolder/" & "file.png")
end tell
```

And how do I get it to work if I want to join a path (string) with a variable (string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System Events** handles POSIX paths a lot better, but this is just another one of those AppleScript oddities.  `POSIX file` will work *outside* of a **Finder** `tell` statement:

```
set x to POSIX file (pathVariable & otherPathVariable)
tell application "Finder"
  activate
  reveal x
end tell
```

but *within* a **Finder** `tell` statement you need to use it as a coercion:

```
tell application "Finder"
  activate
  reveal (pathVariable & otherPathVariable) as POSIX file
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use relative HFS paths. The first line points to the `library` folder of the current user.

```
set libraryFolder to path to library folder from user domain as text
tell application "Finder"
    reveal file (libraryFolder & "com~apple~CloudDocs:MyFolder:" & "file.png")
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to combine strings

```
reveal POSIX file (("/Users/Torben/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/MyFolder/" & "file.png") as text)
```